# selecting rows given criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Oracle sql table called "TEST"

```
id  amount  date
1   0   1/2/2015
2   100 1/2/2015
3   2   5/10/2016
4   55  5/10/2016
```

I want to select rows where there are two rows with the same date, where one amount is 0 and the other amount is greater than 0, and the row with the lower amount also has the lowest id.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to make sure the row with 0 amount also has the lower id of the two rows.

```
select * from TEST
where id in(    
select id   
(select id,
       created_dt,
       sum(case when amount=0 then 1 else case when amount>0 then 2 end end) 
       over (partition by d.created_dt) as checkAmount
from TEST)
where checkAmount = 3)
```

Comment: Are you looking for all possible pairs of ids on a given date or only groups with exactly two rows for a given date?

Answer (score 0):

*I am interpreting your intention as keeping only those groups of dates that have two rows which fits with the query you have already tried. If your question is about pairs of rows that meet the conditions then this approach is not the one you need.*

Depending on the range of your amounts you can use a scaling factor to combine the id and amount into a single value:

```
select created_dt, min(id), max(id), max(amount)
from TEST
group by created_dt
having
        count(*) = 2 and min(amount) = 0 and max(amount) > 0
    and min(10000 * id + amount) = min(10000 * id)
```

Similarly, you could try this (as a substitute for the final condition) though it could result in an overflow without some care. The idea should still be sound :

```
    and max(id) * max(amount) = max(id * amount)
```

Another possibly clever way:

```
    and min(id) = max(case when amount = 0 then id else -id end)
```

Or probably safest and simplest of all, either of these two options:

```
    and min(id) + min(amount) = min(id + amount)
    and max(id) + max(amount) = max(id + amount)
```

The full query is then:

```
select created_dt, min(id), max(id), max(amount)
from TEST
group by created_dt
having
        count(*) = 2 and min(amount) = 0 and max(amount) > 0
    and min(id) + min(amount) = min(id + amount)
```

**EDIT:** Having all the data in one row might truly be an advantage but I realized you may want to keep it in two rows. If you're just returning these values and not other columns it's still easy to get that.
And note that you still have the ids to use with a join to pick them up if necessary.

```
with data as (
    select
        created_dt,
        min(id) as min_id, max(id) as max_id, max(amount) as max_amount
    from TEST
    group by created_dt
    having
            count(*) = 2 and min(amount) = 0 and max(amount) > 0
        and min(id) + min(amount) = min(id + amount)
)
select split.*
from data cross apply (
    values
        (created_dt, min_id, 0),
        (created_dt, max_id, max_amount)
    ) split(created_dt, id, amount)
```

This query can be written without the `with`, `cross apply`, and `values` if those aren't tools at your disposal by some arbitrary edict.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id,  amount, dt ) AS
SELECT  1,   0, DATE '2016-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Valid
SELECT  2, 100, DATE '2016-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Valid
SELECT  3,   2, DATE '2016-10-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Non-zero group
SELECT  4,  55, DATE '2016-10-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Non-zero group
SELECT  5,   5, DATE '2016-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- +ve before zero
SELECT  6,   0, DATE '2016-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- +ve before zero
SELECT  7,  -5, DATE '2016-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- -ve
SELECT  8,   0, DATE '2016-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- More than 2 rows
SELECT  9,   1, DATE '2016-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- More than 2 rows
SELECT 10,   2, DATE '2016-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- More than 2 rows
SELECT 11,   0, DATE '2016-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Valid
SELECT 12,  -1, DATE '2016-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- -ve
SELECT 13,   2, DATE '2016-01-03' FROM DUAL;          -- Valid
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,amount,dt
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE
           WHEN amount = 0 THEN LEAD( CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN id END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY id )
           WHEN amount > 0 THEN LAG( CASE WHEN amount = 0 THEN id END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY id )
           END AS is_valid,
         COUNT( CASE amount WHEN 0 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY dt ) AS num_zeros,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY dt ) AS num_positive
  FROM   test t
)
WHERE is_valid IS NOT NULL
AND   num_zeros    = 1
AND   num_positive = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID     AMOUNT DT                
---------- ---------- -------------------
        11          0 2016-01-03 00:00:00 
        13          2 2016-01-03 00:00:00 
         1          0 2016-02-01 00:00:00 
         2        100 2016-02-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a simple UNION ALL query: Get the amount=0 records for which exist a higher ID with a positive amount on the same date plus get the amount>0 records for which exist a lower ID with a zero amount on the same date.

```
select * 
from test
where amount = 0
and exists
(
  select *
  from test other
  where other.created_dt = test.created_dt
  and other.id > test.id
  and amount > 0
)
union all
select * 
from test
where amount > 0
and exists
(
  select *
  from test other
  where other.created_dt = test.created_dt
  and other.id < test.id
  and amount = 0
);
```

Comment: You're just checking existence but, unless I'm overlooking something, that won't limit the "groups" to one row of each type.

Comment: Well, what do you consider a group? Let's say there are four records for one date, the first two with a zero amount, the next two with a positive amount. I'd show them all, as they all match the criteria (zero amount with a smaller ID then positive amount on the same date). But you are right; the OP has only shown a very simple example with two records so far and we don't know if there is more to consider when there are more rows.

Comment: Yes, but what if there are more? Not show them at all? Getting back to my example with four rows, when I look at row #1 and row #3, I've found two rows matching the given criteria. Same is true for #1 + #4, #2 + #3 and #2 + #4. You are right, tho OP talks about two rows. This is somehow vague. Can there be only two rows for a date, maybe? Then my solution still works. My answer is valid, at least as long as the OP doesn't add further rules on how to treat multiple records with a zero or positive amount for a date.

Comment: I can see your logic. I guess I myself would probably want to see the row ids paired off if that is the intent. You might be right about that.